# A $2$x$2$ Matrix $A$ is invertible if $\det(A) \not= 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

This exercise is from Lay's Linear Algebra textbook (Ch 2.2, #25):

Show that if $ad-bc=0$, then $A$**x**$=$ **0** has more than one solution. Hint: 1st consider $a=b=0$.Then, if $a$ and $b$ are not zero, consider the vector **x**=$\begin{bmatrix}
-b\\
a\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Here is my proof attempt.

Suppose not. Then $\det(A) =0$. Thus $ad-bc=0$. Now, $A=\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)$ $\implies$ $A$ has a free variable $\implies$ there are infinitely many solutions.

Now, let **x** $=a*[-d,c]$, then $A$**x**$=$ $\left(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)$ $\begin{bmatrix}
-d\\
c\\
\end{bmatrix}$ $=$ **0**. Thus, $\exists$ a nontrivial solution. Since there is no unique solution, there is no unique inverse.

Now, let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero. Additionally, let **x**$=\begin{bmatrix}
-b\\
a\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $A$**x**$=$ $\left(\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\right)$ $\begin{bmatrix}
-d\\
c\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
ad-bc\\
\end{bmatrix}$ . But, we assumed that $ad-bc=0$. Therefore, $A$**x**$=$**0**. Once again. $\exists$ a nontrivial solution.

Thus, A $2$x$2$ Matrix $A$ is invertible if $\det(A) \not= 0$.

Comment: Hint, try $x=a*[-d,c]$ for any scalar $a$. What is $Ax$ then?

Comment: @mode_er edited

Comment: @blacknapkins7 this is not a correct proof. You seem to losing track of what you are assuming and what you are trying to prove, for one thing. You show for example that there is a matrix $A$ with det $0$ that has a nontrivial $0$, whereas you are supposed to show that *every* $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ with det $0$ has a nontrivial $0$. In general from reading your posts I don't think you understand how proofs are supposed to go.

Comment: It may be helpful to think of writing a proof this way: Suppose you are giving someone directions on how to get to your place. Then you have to know where they are starting from, and from this, every step has to follow logically from the previous step. You also can't get mixed up on whether they are headed from their house to you, or instead, back the other way--from you to back to their house. Otherwise you end up giving them directions from where they are back to their house, instead of to your house, which is what you want.

Comment: A correction on what I said earlier is in order here. You *do* in fact show that a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ with det $0$ does have a nontrivial $x$ such that $Ax=0$, which shows that a matrix $A$ with det $0$ is not invertible [second-to-last paragraph from the bottom]. But, a) what you wrote the paragraph above, has nothing to do with this, and b) you claim incorrectly that you actually proved the converse--that if a matrix $A$ has a nonzero det, then $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @Mike I appreciate it. I decided not to follow the hints in the book and instead used the answer given below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix} = (ad-bc) I$.